Swift does not know at what Actor is a Task?
I am learning async/await and Task. So i learned that Task basically inherit actor.
Imagine I have a model:
class SomeModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var downloads: [Int] = []

   func doSome() async throw {
      // MAKE URL
      downloads.append(1)

      try await /// MAKE REQUEST
      downloads.append(data) // after request
    
   }
}

And I have a simple View
struct DownloadView: View {

  @EnvironmentObject var model: SomeModel


  var body: some View {
    List {
      // USE model.downloads 
    }
    .task {
        do {
          try await model.doSome()
        } catch {}
    }
}

I get an error that I am updating UI from background thread. Thats ok.
Then i add
func doSome() async throw {
      // MAKE URL
      downloads.append(1)

      try await /// MAKE REQUEST
      await MainActor.run {
            downloads.append(data)
       } // after request
}

And I have still Error. System does not know that first append is Always main actor? Or this is a security from dummies if some on pus some suspended code before first append?
How I understand hierarchical await is needed for System know what tree of sub jobs need to suspend. But a suspension point is after first append, so it could not pass on different actor.
Code for reproduce:
Model
struct DownloadFile: Identifiable {
    var id: String { return name }
    let name: String
    let size: Int
    let date: Date
    
    static let mockFiles = [DownloadFile(name: "File1", size: 100, date: Date()),
                            DownloadFile(name: "File2", size: 100, date: Date()),
                            DownloadFile(name: "File3", size: 100, date: Date()),
                            DownloadFile(name: "File4", size: 100, date: Date()),
                            DownloadFile(name: "File5", size: 100, date: Date()),
                            DownloadFile(name: "FIle6", size: 100, date: Date())]
    
    static let empty = DownloadFile(name: "", size: 0, date: Date())
}

FirstView
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var files: [DownloadFile] = []
    let model: ViewModel
    
    @State var selected = DownloadFile.empty {
      didSet {
        isDisplayingDownload = true
      }
    }
    
    @State var isDisplayingDownload = false
    
    var body: some View {
      NavigationStack {
        VStack {
          // The list of files available for download.
          List {
            Section(content: {
              if files.isEmpty {
                ProgressView().padding()
              }
              ForEach(files) { file in
                Button(action: {
                  selected = file
                }, label: {
                    Text(file.name)
                })
              }
            })
          }
          .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
        }
        .task {
            try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
            files = DownloadFile.mockFiles
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isDisplayingDownload) {
          DownloadView(file: selected).environmentObject(model)
        }
      }
    }
}


Second view
struct DownloadView: View {
    let file: DownloadFile
    @EnvironmentObject var model: ViewModel
    @State var result: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(file.name)
            if model.downloads.isEmpty {
                Button {
                    Task {
                        result = try await model.download(file: file)
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("-- Download --")
                }
            }
            Text(result)
        }
    }
}

viewModel
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var downloads: [String] = []
    
    func download(file: DownloadFile) async throws -> String {
        downloads.append(file.name)

        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))
        return "Download Finished"
    }
}

NEW UPDATE FOR 31.10.2024
So how I understand When Swift see "await" - it mean that next code could be done on other tread that the colling thread, but it will start like  Dispatch.current.aasync.  So Task will start after main thread will finish but on another Tread.

SomeModel method doSome is nonisolated (it is not actor-isolated). And nonisolated async functions run on the “generic executor” (i.e., not the main thread). Change “Strict concurrency checking” build setting to “Complete”, the compiler will warn you of the problems. There are several ways of fixing this, but Apple advises isolating ObservableObject to the main actor. That both solves the thread-safety violation as well as prevents UI updates from background thread. See WWDC 2021’s Discover concurrency in SwiftUI.

So you mean that its ok, because system warning me that it could be potential problem, in the future not in my case? So in every next class i need use isolation?

for now its very hard for me understand new concurrency. Due to forums and questions here on stack more people does not understand this ten understand. I don't understand how using Dispatch.main.async ( in most case this is a Task functionality ) make better performance then Dispatch.global.async. Apple recommend don't use Task.detached why? This not something new just say use Task with async function and Dispatch.async for other background work

“So you mean that its ok, because system warning me that it could be potential problem” … No, I am saying your code is not thread-safe. You should heed the compiler warnings with “Strict concurrency checking” of “Complete”.

“I don't understand how using DispatchQueue.main.async (in most case this is a Task functionality) make better performance then DispatchQueue.global().async.” First, you should generally refrain from using DispatchQueue at all in your Swift concurrency codebase. Second, I would refrain from choosing between main and global() for performance reasons. We use main when need to update the UI, and otherwise use some background queue when doing anything slow that might block the main queue. Now that we can avail ourselves of async API, global is somewhat moot in Swift concurrency.

I found an answer my self. But really no concrete code examples i found in internet for now. How to see concurrent prints in console. I did it. Problem was that Task is Dispatch.main.async so i need also use Dispatch.main.async to see that my download function is not in main thread. Should i Close question?

Move the async func out of the class and make it return the downloads array

“Apple recommend don't use Task.detached why?” … First, unnecessary unstructured concurrency is generally inadvisable (both Task {…} and Task.detached {…}). Second, unlike GCD (in which the caller often determines what thread/queue some called function runs), the concurrency context of some async function is determined by how the called function was defined, and whether you call it from a normal task vs a detached task is often immaterial. Detached tasks have some very narrow use-cases, but it is no where nearly as common as a global queue back in the GCD days.

“Should i Close question?” … Unless you think your answer will be helpful to future readers, yes, you should just delete the question. However if you think your answer would be helpful to future readers, feel free to post an answer to your own question. But I should warn you that if you post an answer contemplating using any DispatchQueue related solutions to your Swift concurrency codebase problems, it will likely be swiftly down-voted, as mixing GCD with Swift concurrency is almost always a mistake.

I can only underline what @Rob has said: GCD and Swift Concurrency should not be used together, as it is very likely to violate the runtime contract of Swift Concurrency. At worst, this produces deadlocks.

another tip you could add print("/(Thread.current)") in your code to see if you are on main Thread (1) or not and then alter delete the print statement when you understand it

Looking at threads is can be misleading. Use MainActor.preconditionIsolated().

Too much text about Actors and Isolation. For someone who don't understand how task is worked, and someone who still think Task.detached is bad, and have very narrow use-cases.
So what I understand after some experiments and learning. All is simple.
Apple did (like every time) old staff from past years in new cover.
so:

All async staff is sync. If you want to run it async use Task. (but even you can't use it without task).

Task = DispatchQueue.current.async - But on every await system could change Thread.


What does it mean?
If you have something like this:
class A {
    func first() async {
        for i in 0...1000 {
            print(" \(i)")
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let a = A()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
        Task {
            await a.first()
        }
        second()
    }

    func second() {
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5)
        for i in 0...1000 {
            print("♥️ \(i)")
        }
    }
}

Second() will always print first, but First() could print on other Thread then main
If you need DispatchQueue.global.async you use Task.detached

await its like sync on GCD.
This code :
 Task {
     await a.first()
 }

is something like:
 DispatchQueue.current.async {
     DispatchQueue.global().async {
         DispatchQueue.global().sync {
             a.first
         }
     }
 }



What does it mean? - If you have @MainActor functions in your class for updating @Published properties, and you for example what update a Progress of some background work (for example AsyncSequence) you must use Task.detached (what ever Apple say)
Apple problem is that they every time think that all apps in Store is 3 screen MVP whit one button and one endpoint.

The term thread isn’t used with the new concurrency


System does not know that first append is Always main actor?

How should the “system” (or more precisely the compiler) know this at this point?
There is no magic in Swift Concurrency that would recognize that if you access a property in one code location from a specific actor, all accesses to that property should be protected with that actor.
In your case, SomeModel is not bound to a specific actor, nor is the doSome function.
The task modifier creates a new top level task and if you call an async method within this task which is not bound to a specific actor, you have the described issue.
Child tasks inherit the actor of the top-level task to which they belong. Top-level tasks run the specified operation asynchronously on behalf of the current actor. But async methods are bound to the actor of their type and not to the actor of the caller of the method.
So what you actually should do is bind your view model to the main actor:
@MainActor
final class SomeModel: ObservableObject {
    // ...
}

This means that access to all properties is protected by the MainActor and any attempt to access a property from another actor must take place as an async call. This is then enforced by the compiler and makes it clear that a special protected call must take place at this point.
Roughly speaking, it is as if you have to wait for a lock at this point, with the difference that the calling thread is not blocked as a result.
Or, if you are sure of what you are doing, just bind the downloads property and maybe the doSome method to the MainActor and make sure that all other accesses to SomeModel are protected accordingly:
final class SomeModel: ObservableObject {
    @MainActor @Published private(set) var downloads: [Int] = []

    // ...

    @MainActor
    func doSome() async throw {
        // ...
    }
}

At first glance, your implementation listed below has fairly clear concurrency issues:
func doSome() async throw {
      // MAKE URL
      downloads.append(1)

      try await /// MAKE REQUEST
      await MainActor.run {
            downloads.append(data)
       } // after request
}

Since the class of the method is not bound to any actor, the asynchronous doSome function can be called by practically any task (and therefore thread).
This means that the method can also be called several times concurrently and in the first line you already make a concurrent access to downloads, which is a problem because nothing protects downloads at this point.
And while your second access to downloads is made on the MainActor, other tasks may still make another concurrent call to doSome and access downloads in the first line of this method.
I would generally recommend activating the “strict concurrency checking” option, which will detect a lot of concurrency issues at compile time and emit errors.
See here and here.
This mode can also be activated with Swift 5, but does not show as many possible errors as in Swift 6 mode.

Strange that the warning is in live. So this mean that in real time code does not understand that it is in main actor. Thats strange. Really i should not see purple warning because i am on main actor. You sad " Child tasks inherit the actor of the top-level task to which they belong, but for top-level tasks you must specifically specify an actor." every time i see this. What at this meaning is a task? Van you provide line of code? Parent task inherit actor in context it is created so parent task is created in main actor. Dos system say that it could be problem here, in the future, am I right?

If you do get the mentioned warning, then your code isn't running on the main actor. The runtime detection of SwiftUI works properly in this regard and you need to do sth. about this now - not in the future, as it's a serious issue.
A top level task is sth. you usually create explicitly by using one of the Task methods. Note where the documentation says "a new top-level task". I really recommend learning the basics and terminology of Swift Concurrency as it will help you understand a lot of the pitfalls.

I think this is a bad idea, ObservableObject is Combine and to use async/await its .task. Best not mix them up. Put the async func in a struct and make it return a result.

@Dragonboh Here are a few resources to help you learn the basics of Swift Concurrency: The Swift Programming Language (6)
Concurrency, Explore structured concurrency in Swift, Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes, Beyond the basics of structured concurrency

@malhal I'm not quite sure what you're referring to. It's absolutely fine to use structured concurrency in an ObservableObject implementation even though it's using a publisher in the background. Even Apple recommends binding an ObservableObject to the MainActor to use Swift concurrency.

Apple don’t recommend that. They recommend removing the Combine ObservableObject and using async funcs or AsyncStreams. .task provides the lifetime like an object would so you don’t need an object.

@malhal Anyone can see here that this is exactly what Apple recommends.
Regardless of this, there are many places where Apple has created APIs where Combine and Swift Concurrency interlock. Ultimately, the AsyncStream implementation, for example, is still a long way from being a replacement for Combine. Even with the help of swift-async-algorithms. From experience with several large projects, I can say that it is absolutely fine to mix Combine with Swift Concurrency.

In WWDC 2021’s Discover concurrency in SwiftUI, they explicitly suggest if using Swift concurrency with an ObservableObject, one should isolate it to the main actor. They reiterate this in Swift concurrency: Update a sample app. Now, if your minimum OS target supports Observation, as discussed in Discover Observation in SwiftUI, then you should do that.

Your 2021 link was before .task. Your 2022 link that intern has mistakenly put the controller in the model and I remember other major flaws in their code

@Rob I agree, if you can use the Observable macro in your project, you should do so. But this has nothing directly to do with Swift Concurrency, but the way SwiftUI handles state changes through ObservableObject  implementations and the limitations that have arisen as a result.
However, there is no good reason to say just because an object implements ObservableObject that you cannot or should not use structured concurrency in it. At least I haven't heard a sensible argument in the comments of this question yet.

@ITGuy – No disagreement here. I was just sharing those links for malhal, who suggested the “Apple [doesn’t] recommend that”, when clearly they have, and repeatedly so. And I respectfully disagree with him regarding the suggestion that the introduction of task view modifier changes anything in this regard.

@ITGuy i watched all and readed all. Nothing and nowhere explain how Task work. If I put for in loop in await function it is working on different thread but start only when MainThread is free. So it should know it can make something on MainActor
